# Не выводится галерея modx

Tags: modx, gallery

Установил расширение Gallery, создал tv с именем gallery, тип ввода - "galleryalbumlist", тип вывода - "По умолчанию".

Вывожу в ресурсе - [[*gallery]].
Ничего не выводится.

Для каждой записи блога должна быть галерея ...

Answer (score 1):

Нашел способ как сделать с помощью расширения MIGx